# How to run mysql scripts in docker image?

Tags: mysql, docker

In my Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:5.7

ADD ./mysql_scripts /mysql_scripts 
WORKDIR /mysql_scripts
RUN mysql -u root -p < create_user.sql &&\
    mysql -u root -p < create_database.sql &&\
    mysql -u root -p < create_tables.sql

EXPOSE 3306
```

but when I build that image I have problem like:`Enter password: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot run those `mysql` commands, because the container is not running yet, so neither is MySQL.

What you can do is copy your `.sql` files to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. MySQL will run all `.sql`, `.sql.gz` and `.sh` located in this directory after initialization, which would result in the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:5.7

COPY ./mysql_scripts /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

EXPOSE 3306
```

[More information can be found on the dockerhub page of mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

Answer (score 4):

You can not import database at build time, as every `RUN` command run in separate shell plus MySQL process also not ready to accept the connection.

You can take benefits from **docker entrypoint** that does these out of the box.

```
COPY create_user.sql  /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY create_database.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY create_tables.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

So when the container started it will run the above script in **alphabetical order**

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, **it will execute files with extensions `.sh, .sql and .sql.gz`** that are found in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified by the `MYSQL_DATABASE` variable.

[mysql-docker-init-db](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

Also you use `MYSQL_USER` to create user.